# overlapping of two fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to replace fragment main with fragment login but when i call below code,the two fragments overlap(as shown in picture)...

```
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction=getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.maincontent,new login())
                                  .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
                                   .addToBackStack(null)
                                   .commit();
```

i tried to add background in fragment as proposed by other questions but it did not solve my problem ... please help i have tried android.R.id.content but that hides my navigation drawer behind the login fragment on replace ....

main_activity.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/drawerlayout">

----> main fragment
        <fragment 
            android:background="#202020"  
            android:name="com.example.juju.Main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/maincontent"></fragment>
----->navigation fragment
        <fragment
            android:divider="@null"
            android:background="#202020"  
            android:name="com.example.juju.navigationdrawer"   
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="left">
        </fragment>
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Why not make the login as another activity?

Comment: i need to implement it using fragment.... coding is much better using fragment... just this problem has crop up ...

Comment: were you able to solve this ? If yes then guide us too. Thanks.

Comment: As stated by @Abhinav arora its much better to use a Viewgroup like relativelayout ,framelayout etc.This would help in easy replacing of fragment.

Comment: Basically when we are adding a fragment in our xml code the fragment is not getting replace using fragmenttransaction.replace so best option would be to inflate the first fragment in the viewgroup during oncreate of the activity correspondingly replace the fragments as when needed .

Answer (score 2):

Use FrameLayout instead of Fragment in your XML file.
See what you have used right now is a Fragment layout. It is used with this attribute :- android:name="com.package.fragmentActivity" where fragmentActivity is the fragment class. To do what you are trying to do, inflating layout and replacing them, FrameLayout works well. Why other layouts like LinearLayout or Relative doesn't work well, I have no idea about that. I am telling you according to my personal experience and a little internet research